# SSD no media on Windows 10

Tags: ssd, media

I have an SSD 1Tb drive in an external enclosure.  When plugging it in on a Windows 10 USB port, it shows a 'no media' error.  If I install the SSD internally it works fine.

Tried on various machine with the same result.  The external enclosure have been tested with another SSD drive (512Mb) and is working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try another enclosure - some of them change the apparent block size, so if you format it in that enclosure it works, if you format it elsewhere it doesn't.

Comment: "No media" shouldn't have anything to do with block size; the error means there _are no blocks_ to begin with. Wrong block size would just cause the partition table to be unrecognizable. Have you tested this enclosure with other 1TB or larger disks (not necessarily SSDs)?

Comment: The enclosure is only for SSD.  I have not tested another 1 TB drive, but have tested another enclosure, which also have the same issue.

Comment: Maybe the power provided by the USB port is not enough to bring up the drive.

Comment: Was the other enclosure of the same model? I'm presuming the SSD is SATA (either M.2 or 2.5")? If it's M.2, then this error will likely occur if it's an NVMe SSD (I've never seen a USB enclosure that supports NVMe). Please share model numbers and more information.